# How to make a socket server that only accepts one connection?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I write a TCP server using Python. I want the server 
only accept on client connection.

I use the [`listen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) function

```
listen(1)
```

but the server still can accepts more than one connection.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen):

> If backlog is specified, it must be at least 0 (if it is lower, it is set to 0); it specifies the number of unaccepted connections that the system will allow before refusing new connections.

So if you use `listen(1)` you allow one unaccepted connection. If you want to allow no unaccepted connections, you must use `listen(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one connection, pleae don't use loop for `socket.accept()` in- connections.

### demo code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import socket


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_addr = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
server.bind(server_addr)
server.listen(1)
print("listening on {}".format(server_addr))
client, client_addr = server.accept()

for i in range(10):
    client.send("num: {}\n".format(i))
    time.sleep(1)

raw_input('')
```