# How can I limit my server to only accept one client socket connection at a time?

Tags: python, sockets

I've seen other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007785/how-to-make-a-socket-server-that-only-accepts-one-connection) that don't seem to find a satisfactory answer. I'm trying to create a server using Pythons `socket` library that connects to one and only one client at a time. Further requests to connect should be denied with a `ConnectionRefusedError`. On the server side, here's my code:

```py
import socket 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(0)
clientsocket, address = s.accept()

while True:
    pass
```

Next, open up a Python terminal to create clients:

```py
>>> import socket
>>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
>>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
>>> socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

From this, I'm gathering that the server allowed me to connect *two* clients before throwing the `ConnectionRefusedError`. I'm setting the backlog to 0 with the `s.listen(0)` command, so I'm very confused as to how I could have two connections being accepted here. How can I make it such that my server denies further connection requests after connecting to the first client?

Comment: You have to close the listening socket to prevent new connections.

Comment: Does this terminate my connection with the client?

Comment: No, that's in `clientsocket`. Nothing you do to `s` will affect that.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was missing. Thank you.